# Regex: Getting the width and height from a tag

Tags: php, regex

I'm building a wysiwyg extension and have built a library for image uploading and handling. 
To further integrate in the code I want to extract some data from the wysiwyg output like so:

```
$content = '<img class="left media-id-1657" src="someurl" width="113" height="97" />';
preg_match_all('/<[^>]*class="[^"]*\media-id-([0-9]{1,10})\b[^"]*"[^>]*>/i', $content, $matches);
```

This gives me the given id, which in this case is `1657`. It works great and no change is needed.

But now I also need to get the width (and height). But for some stupid reason I can't extract it. I came up with this:

```
/<[^>]*class="[^"]*\media-id-([0-9]{1,10})\b[^"]*width="([0-9]{1,10})"[^>]*>/i
```

But it's not doing what I want as it gives 0 matches. 
http://regexr.com/3h14n

Comment: You could explode the string first, then your regex would be much more simple to create ( with the addition of a foreach).

Comment: What about when the order of the attributes changes? Use a parser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
preg_match( '/width="(.*?)"/', $content, $matchesWidth);
preg_match( '/height="(.*?)"/', $content, $matchesHeight);
print_r($matchesWidth[1]); //Output 113
print_r($matchesHeight[1]); //Output 97
```

Comment: I suspect the OP wants to make sure the `media-id` part of the string is there before he extracts. Hence the long Regex.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, already got it after some playing around.

```
/<[^>]*class="[^"]*\media-id-([0-9]{1,10})\b[^"]*"[^>]*width="([0-9]{1,10})"[^>]*height="([0-9]{1,10})"[^>]*>/i
```

Comment: - Get next where not ">". 
- Search for "width=" 
- Get variable
- Close tag

Answer (score 0):

There are quotes in between the `\b` and the `width` parts of the string, but not the regex.

Does this work:

```
/<[^>]*class="[^"]*\media-id-([0-9]{1,10})\b.*width="([0-9]{1,10})"[^>]*>/i
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it all with one regex, this should work for the params in the current order:

```
<img class="\D+(\d+)".*?width="(\d+)" height="(\d+)"
```

That being said, if there are extra spaces between width, height or anything else it won't.  You'll have to code for those issues, but if you are confident the data will always be in that format it will work.  Personally I would break it into 3 regexes.  Your current one and then for height and width very simple:

```
width="(\d+)"
height="(\d+)"
```